# Python Flask can't save file from post request

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I am using a Flask API to handle file posting.

### Code

```
@app.route("/post_image", methods=POST)
def post_image():
    """récupère une image et l'enregistre dans la base de données"""
    # vérifie si la requête contient un fichier
    if "file" not in request.files:
        msg = "fichier absent"
        print(msg)
        return  {message: msg}
    file = request.files["file"]
    plate = request.form["plate"]
    print(f"Une image est en cours d'enregistrement pour le véhicule immatriculé {plate}")
    # vérifie si le fichier est autorisé
    print("Vérification du fichier ...")
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename, ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']):
        print("Fichier valide, enregsitrement")
        # création du nom de fichier sécurisé
        # création du dossier de réception
        path = app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + plate + "/"
        try:
            os.mkdir(path)
        except FileExistsError:
            print("Le dossier existe déjà")
        # création de l'image
        save_path = get_new_file_path(path, file.filename)
        print(f"Enregistrement du fichier dans le chemin suivant : {save_path}")
        file.save(save_path, buffer_size=128000)
        file.close()
        msg = "fichier enregsitré"
        return {"message": msg}
    print("Fichier non autorisé")
    return {"message": "erreur"}
```

### [Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsYef.png)

```
Une image est en cours d'enregistrement pour le véhicule immatriculé FH487WL
Vérification du fichier ...
Fichier valide, enregsitrement
Le dossier existe déjà
Enregistrement du fichier dans le chemin suivant : /home/ubuntu/api/data/car_images/FH487WL/0.jpg
```

### Objective

I want this function to save a file that I uploaded on the server side. I only upload images, and the function `get_new_file_path` is a combination between `secure_filename` (from werkzeug) and `os.path.join`.

I am serving with Gunicorn.

### Problem

As I am printing on the server side, I notice that the method "save" of the "file" object just wont stop. I've been waiting for multiple minutes and I don't think it should be taking that long...

### Comment

The file do get saved when I kill the Gunicorn Process with CTRL + C.

### Solutions tried

1. Closing all files from server so no file access is violated.
2. Restarting the API, updating pip and restarting the Linux machine (ec2 t3.micro Ubuntu).
3. Removing the function `secure_filename` from `werkzeug`.
4. Lurking the docs.
5. Using Threading to not wait the function to end properly (kind of a heresy tbh).

It would be convenient if someone could help me solve this issue.

Comment: have you tried it on a local machine? to rule out if there is an access issue with s3. also, in the log you posted, it seems like the file already exists. to debug, pls share the HTML file too, so it's easy to debug.

Comment: @simpleApp thank you for the idea. however, I just found a solution. I wan't supposed to close the file after saving it (even though the documentation asked it). Now it works.
Thank you again for your time

Comment: awesome you found a solution. A suggestion & comment, 
1. when requesting the user to upload a file, you can restrict types to upload example `<input type="file" name="file" accept=".jpeg,.png,.JPG">` [HTML file upload filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)
2. FYI.. was looking the support methods on file(werkzeug.datastructures.file_storage.FileStorage), it does support `close`[reference](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.FileStorage.html)

Comment: Yeah I saw that the `close` statement worked. It really closed the file. However, when I tried to later open the file, it didn't work at all. (I/O operation on closed file.)
Thank you for the suggestion, but I didn't mention that my API is completely headless. (so no HTML page)